# Bsearch in C to match within a range of elements, instead of a specific element

Tags: c, search, bsearch

I'm trying to do a binary search of an array of structs which contain hex addresses. Each struct holds a few addresses, and when I give an input address, I want to find the struct that has the range which spans my input address, not just the exact match to the address of the start of the struct.

Can I do this with bsearch? I am having trouble finding a compare function that would work for this.

ptrSymbolArray contains the original data. This function looks kind of pointless because to make this simpler I have eliminated a condition which I use on data from ptrSymbolArray. Here I include everything from that original data.

```
typedef struct{
  int name;
  int address;
} testStruct

static testStruct **fillArray(testStruct *ptrSymbolArray, int *arraySize,
                char *ptrNameArray, int *arrcount){
  testStruct **fillArray = malloc((*arraySize)*sizeof(testStruct));
  for(int i=0; i< *arraySize; i++){  
      fillArray[*arrcount] = ptrSymbolArray+i;
      (*arrcount)++;
    }
  }
  return fillArray;
}
```

The data I am actually going through are files which store the names, addresses, etc. of functions in a c file. I want to input an address to know which function I am in. To do this I need to be able to match an address within a struct, not just the address at the start of the struct.

Comment: "the struct that has the range which spans my input address" - it's not clear what you mean by this. Can you provide some sample code showing an example of an array and the structs in it, and what output you want for what input to your search function?

Comment: I just edited, and would really appreciate some help!

Comment: I tried to do a qsort, but that also doesn't work. I get no errors, and everything runs, but the output is not sorted.